# download file then redirect to some page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

the problem is that pdf is not downloading and page redirect to other page

```
$this->proposal_model->auto_save($data,$itemCount,$name0,$name1,$name2,$name3,$name4,$type,$project_id);
$this->load->view("pdf-download",$data);
redirect('proposal/new_proposal');
```

**pdf is not downloading and page redirect**

**But without redirect function pdf start downloading**

Comment: Can you re-format your question

Comment: What is `pdf-download`'s content? also you can't redirect and download a file at the same time

Comment: Please confirm.  You would like the page to prompt a user to download or open a pdf and then forward them to another page?

Comment: Try to use jquery to redirect page

Comment: @pendo that exactly i want

Comment: @RyukLee how is he going to use jquery/js when the page itself is a file download payload?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you wanted but **long story short: you can't force a download then redirect a page.** Both have to do with setting headers, one for a file download, and one for a location - the two can't be mixed - at least not without one or the other functioning incorrectly. And you probably can't use js to do this without something like deceze suggested here: [Force download with PHP then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574878/force-download-with-php-then-redirect?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which doesn't seem like what you want to accomplish as the redirecting is happening before serving the download. Similarly, netcoder's answer in the aforementioned link doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: you said that set two header one for download and other for location.the problem is that i don't know how to do that i just want please give me an example so that i can fix my problem.thanku

Comment: i said "you can't force a download then redirect a page" "the two can't be mixed" as you can see in the example I linked setting up two headers using boundaries (netcoder answer) doesn't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should have three functions in your controller, as it relates to this:

1. proposal/loadpdf
2. proposal/someotherview
3. proposal/new_proposal

Contents of the controller method proposal/loadpdf

```
$pdf = file_get_contents('thepdftoread.pdf');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=whateveryouwanttocallpdf.pdf");
readfile($pdfx);
```

Contents of the 'someotherview', that you are starting from (where you click the link)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  $(function(){ //wait for body to load before we execute whatever is in here
    $("a.openPDF").click(function(){
      window.open('proposal/loadpdf','name of window');
      location.href = '/proposal/new_proposal'; //forward to proposal/new_proposal
    })
  })
</script>
</body>
<a href="#" class="openPDF">Click me!</a>
</html>
```